# offset limit mysql query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, offset

Lets say I have a table User.
I have few thousands record in my table.

When I tried

```
User.where("category = 'Normal'").offset(3000).limit(10)
```

it return me the user which his id's start from 4184

I was thinking is that offset will start from 4001 instead? I tried check user with id 4000 and 4001, there are these two record exists.

Any constraint or situation will have this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want find_in_batches? http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_in_batches

Comment: I just want to know how it work :D thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`User.offset(3000)` will select from the 3001st user. It doesn't take into account how the User `id`.

In your case, the users with `id` 4000 and 4001 are among the first 3000 users.

If you want to select from the 4001st user:

```
User.where('category IS ? AND id >= ?', 'Normal', 4001).limit(10)
```